# How to create macro/record actions while modeling

Tags: python, modeling, scripting, edit-mode

I'd like to record my actions and create a macro. I've tried allready two things:

1) copying actions from Info panel and pasting them to text aditor. Then adding the lines:

```
import bpy
from mathutils import Vector, Matrix, Quaternion, Euler, Color
```

It works on the "Object" mode, but when I'm working on the "edit"mode, it does not record what vertice or face was selected. For example, if I'm creating box and then extruding the top face it looks like this:

```
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(radius=1, view_align=False, enter_editmode=False, location=(-4.74089, -5.86062, 3.95351), layers=(True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False))
bpy.context.space_data.context = 'OBJECT'
bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
bpy.ops.mesh.extrude_region_move(MESH_OT_extrude_region={"mirror":False}, TRANSFORM_OT_translate={"value":(0, 0, 0.788862), "constraint_axis":(False, False, True), "constraint_orientation":'NORMAL', "mirror":False, "proportional":'DISABLED', "proportional_edit_falloff":'SMOOTH', "proportional_size":1, "snap":False, "snap_target":'CLOSEST', "snap_point":(0, 0, 0), "snap_align":False, "snap_normal":(0, 0, 0), "gpencil_strokes":False, "texture_space":False, "remove_on_cancel":False, "release_confirm":False})
bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=(0, 0, -0.434886), constraint_axis=(False, False, True), constraint_orientation='GLOBAL', mirror=False, proportional='DISABLED', proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=1, release_confirm=True) # I've slected another face and moved it. No information here on which one.
```

so there is no information on what face or vertex was moved or extruded.

2) Macro Recorder found [here](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Development/Macros_Recorder) just doesn't work. It creates the template but do not record enything. All it produces is this:

```
import bpy
from mathutils import Vector, Matrix, Quaternion, Euler, Color

class MacroOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "macro.macro"
    bl_label = "Macro"

    def execute(self, context):

        return {'FINISHED'}

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_module(__name__)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

So, is there a way to record all actions, including face selection?

Comment: I've had the same problem and the first thing I did was remove the addon completely from Blender and reinstall it. After that, I notice that this addon seems to have problems with "global" actions... E.g.: If you start recording then inset a face and extrude it using the global constraint, it will not record for some reason... You have to be mindful to use local or normal constraints to create the desired effects. I don't get it why certain things don't work though and why it produces these empty scripts... I'm voting up your question because I also need clarification!

Comment: Not sure if this can help u but have a look at the chosen answer https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/102121/add-shortcut-for-merge-last-and-merge-first

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use "CommandRecorder" addon , its record actions while modeling too.

https://github.com/Muthird/CommandRecorder2.8

[image]