# How to acces to EnumProperty value outside of "class SearchEnumOperator"?

Tags: python, operator, panel

I can't understand how to get the value of an EnumProperty outside this operator.
This is an example with the panel where I would like to show the current value of this EnumProperty:

```
class SearchEnumOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "object.search_enum_operator"
    bl_label = "Search Enum Operator"
    bl_property = "my_search"

    my_search: EnumProperty(
        name="My Search",
        items=(
            ('FOO', "Foo", ""),
            ('BAR', "Bar", ""),
            ('BAZ', "Baz", ""),
        ),
    )

    def execute(self, context):
        self.report({'INFO'}, "Selected:" + self.my_search)
        return {'FINISHED'}

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        context.window_manager.invoke_search_popup(self)
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

class CustomMenu(bpy.types.Menu):
    bl_label = "Custom Menu"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_MT_custom_menu"

    def draw(self, context):

        layout = self.layout
        ###Noob example:
        #layout.label(text = SearchEnumOperator.my_search)<---------?
```

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/163129/how-can-i-access-view3d-select-circle-radius-value/163130#163130

Comment: Ty for this tips, So actually, it seems like a bad practice, I think I'll have to change my approach to that enumproperty.

Comment: Not sure what you mean re bad practice. If you want to expand the enum in a menu can use `layout.operator_menu_enum`  (or whatever it's called consult docs) as shown somewhat in https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/102157/15543   Might also need to have REGISTER in operator bl_options for it to show up in last operator used.