# How to model one section of the mesh and affect other selected parts on the same mesh

Tags: modeling

How is it possible to model one section of the mesh, for example the one I have selected in the Red rectangle, and to be able to affect other selected parts on the mesh (Blue).

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do [actions recording](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56005/how-to-create-macro-record-actions-while-modeling). Without using any addons, you could temporarily separate the areas you want to have modeled the same way by selecting each area in *Edit Mode* and pressing <kbd>P</kbd> *> Selection* to separate as new object. Then set the origin using <kbd>RMB</kbd> > *Set Origin > Origin to Geometry*. Then in *Object Mode* select all separated objects and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> *> Link Object Data*. Now you can model any of these meshes and it will get reflected to all the objects. Once you are done, select all objects and join with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> then <kbd>tab</kbd> into *Edit Mode* and press <kbd>A</kbd> to select all faces then <kbd>M</kbd> *> Merge By Distance* to join all vertices together again.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: you're welcome! :)